# Insert line break into string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this a repeat question, but I tried a lot of things and none of them worked. Essentially, I have:

```
var med = word.replace("!", '<br />');            
(div.get(0)).textContent = med;
```

Side note: the div has a `<p>` inside of it and that is what I am changing. Thank you for any advice in advance!

Comment: maybe a jsfiddle link could be useful.

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: It wont insert a line break, like I think it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see the whole of your code so I'm not sure what your HTML looks like. Try this code:

```
var str = jQuery('p').html();
str = str.replace('!', '<br />');
jQuery('p').html(str);
```

There is a jsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/pavkr/bq8be893/

You could simplify the code but this is basically just to show you how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You have to insert the content as html rather than as text. Do it like this:

```
var med = word.replace("!", '<br />');            
(div.get(0)).innerHtml = med;
```